# How do I delete specific dataframe rows based on a columns value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns ("Date" and "Gross Margin). I want to delete rows based on what the value in the "Date" column is. This is my dataframe:

```
       Date        Gross Margin

0   2021-03-31       44.79%
1   2020-12-31       44.53%
2   2020-09-30       44.47%
3   2020-06-30       44.36%
4   2020-03-31       43.69%
..         ...          ...
57  2006-12-31       49.65%
58  2006-09-30       52.56%
59  2006-06-30       49.86%
60  2006-03-31       46.20%
61  2005-12-31       40.88%
```

I want to delete every row where the "Date" value doesn't end with "12-31". I read some similar posts on this and the pandas.drop() function seemed to be the solution, but I haven't figured out how to use it for this specific case.

Please leave any suggestions as to what I should do.

Comment: what is the output of `df['Date'].dtype`?

Comment: You can select the required rows like this, `df = df.loc[~df['Date'].str.contains('12-31')]`

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are using a consistent format, you can do it like this:

```
df = df[df['Date'].str.contains("12-31", regex=False)]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code, where you match the day and month.

```py
df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df = df[df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d') == '12-31']
```

Comment: or `df.Date.dt.month == 12 & df.Date.dt.day == 31` @oreopot

Comment: `dt.strftime` will again convert it into string-based values. Which will take up the processing time. My suggestion just accesses the particular attributes and hence optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the date formatted as year-month-day

```
df = df[~df['Date'].str.endswith('12-31')]
```

Comment: This code deletes the rows that ends with '12-31'. I wanted to delete the ones that didn't end with '12-31'. This code works in my case though since the dates only end in 4 different ways so I can copy paste this for the dates I don't want. But is there a 1 line code solution to this? Thanks!